# Does "One example of that would be it's trophic cascade" make sense?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, terminology, phrasing, biology

I'm trying to write a paragraph for a question for my biology class.  The question is "How are organisms (and non-living things) interconnected within Serengeti National Park?  He wants us to include "Trophic Cascade" and "Keystone Species" from our vocabulary list.  I know what I'm going to write, I just don't know if I'm using this sentence correctly.

Comment: The text in your title is *ungrammatical* (incorrectly written; ***it's = it is, its = belonging to it***). But other than that it could only "make sense" if we knew what "**it**" refers to. Besides which [trophic cascade](https://www.britannica.com/science/trophic-cascade) probably won't be a familiar term to most people.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I had fixed it.  However, regarding the last part, I have to use the word as per my teacher's request.

Comment: One example of ***what*** would be "its trophic cascade"? I'll assume "**it**" is "the Serengeti National Park", but without knowing what "**that**" is I still can't have any idea what you're actually saying. So I've no idea if it makes sense to say it.

Comment: "it is (it's) *a* trophic cascade" might suit better if I get your sense. Presumably you would refer to a particular species in your analysis and remark that it's a keystone species or even *the* keystone in your view. We can't identify one for you here, that's your job.